# MSVC9's preprocessor not worked properly?

Tags: compilation, preprocessor

I try to compile the squish library subproject in the Torque3D engine project.
I got compiling error:

```
simd_ve.h
..\..\..\..\..\SourceLib\Torque3D\Torque3D-3.6.3\Engine\lib\squish\simd_ve.h(29) : fatal error C1083: Can't load file include: altivec.h: No such file or directory
```

In `lib readme` they say:

```
"By default, the library is built using Altivec optimisations.
To change this either change or remove SQUISH_USE_ALTIVEC=1 from the preprocessor symbols."
```

But `SQUISH_USE_ALTIVEC` are not in the project properties and a popup helper in editor show `SQUISH_USE_ALTIVEC = 0`.

I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Try setting `SQUISH_USE_SSE=2` in the preprocessor settings for the project.

Comment: All cpp-ies compiled well, but whole library building encountered this error

Comment: If a header file is not found you should check it is in the INCLUDE path before accusing the preprocessor. Check the actual parameters of the compiler/preprocessor call. If the rules in the makefile don't setup them properly you should consider to tag the question with the appropriate tag of the library or project that you try to build.

Comment: I mean the preprocessor not see that SQUISH_USE_ALTIVEC is null and it include file "simd_ve.h"